# How to convert image to Base64 string, and convert back to image, save to azure blob

Tags: azure, powershell, base64, blob

Hope I am describing this correctly, and probably something really simple

trying to pass an image as a base64 string, inside a json payload, to an azure function written in Powershell, all while aiming to have it end up as an image inside a structured azure blob storage.

Encode local file to Base64:

```
$content = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$fileName")))
```

No issues packaging, sending, and receiving the json payload.

in the Azure function, http trigger

Decode base64

```
$image = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64Content))
```

from there, output to blob:

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $ImageBytes
```

Standard Bindings for output:

```
{
   "name": "outputBlob",
   "path": "container/{filename}",
   "connection": "connectionName",
   "direction": "out",
   "type": "blob"
}
```

The resulting blob is not the an image, assuming it is the decode.

thanks in advance..

Comment: What are the issues you're running into? Please edit your question and provide that information. Also from where `$ImageBytes` is coming? Is it a typo and should be `$bytes`?

Comment: Could you please descibe your issue in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding  the issue, please refer to the following code

function code

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$image=$Request.Body.Image

#read base64 image as bytes
$imageBytes=[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($image)

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value  $imageBytes
```

Standard Bindings for output:

```
{
   "name": "outputBlob",
   "path": "outcontainer/{filename}",
   "connection": "connectionName",
   "direction": "out",
   "type": "blob"
}
```

the script used to send request

```
$fileName="faces.jpg"
$content=Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding Byte
$image=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($content)

$body= @{"fileName"=$fileName;"image"=$image}|convertto-json

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "<url>" -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
```

[image]
[image]